# ReferenceError when trying to send notification with Firebase via Node.js

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I am trying to send a notification via Functions on Firebase.
I am doing the notification programming on JavaScript via Node.js. 
Upon clicking `Send Friend Request` from one account, the other person is suppose to get a notification as specified on the payload of the JavaScript file I have attached below. 
I keep getting the following error on my Firebase Functions

> ReferenceError: event is not defined.

Here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ3T5.png) of the exact error.

Here is my JavaScript file:

```
/*
 * Functions SDK : is required to work with firebase functions.
 * Admin SDK : is required to send Notification using functions.
 */

//This runs JavaScript in Strict Mode, which prevents the use of things such as undefined variables.
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


/*
 * 'OnWrite' works as 'addValueEventListener' for android. It will fire the function
 * everytime there is some item added, removed or changed from the provided 'database.ref'
 * 'sendNotification' is the name of the function, which can be changed according to
 * your requirement
 */

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{retrieveUserId}/{notificationId}').onWrite((data, context) => {


  /*
   * You can store values as variables from the 'database.ref'
   * Just like here, I've done for 'user_id' and 'notification'
   */

  const retrieveUserId = context.params.retrieveUserId;
  const notificationId = context.params.notificationId;

  console.log('User id is : ', retrieveUserId);

  //Prevents notification being sent if there are no logs of notifications in the database.

  if (!event.data.val()) {

    return console.log('A notification has been deleted from the database : ', notificationId);

  }

  const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${retrieveUserId}/device_token`).once('value');

  return deviceToken.then(result => {

    const tokenId = result.val();


    const payload = {
    notification: {
        title: "Friend Request",
        body: "You have received a friend request from Slim Shady",
        icon: "default"
    }
  };

  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokenId, payload).then(response => {

    return console.log('Notification was sent to the user');

  });


  });





});
```

This is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/728AD.png) of parents and children of my Firebase database referred to in the JavaScript file.

As the error states an event not being defined, I'm trying to figure out which event I have not defined.

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined event in this code block:

```
if (!event.data.val()) {
```

Comment: How can I fix this??